# How is this realtime database filter done?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

On this [page](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/muscle/id/6/muscle/neck) there is a form on the left side that filters MySql query results in real time.

My guess it has something to do with AJAX or similar language.

Can someone point me at what direction should I look to make a realtime-changing search results filter form.

Or what should I search for to find a working example or tutorial to make something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's definetly AJAX, but AJAX is not a programming language, it's Asynchronous Javascript and XML. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. jQuery is probably the easiest way to do something like that.

```
if($('#checkbox').is('::checked')){
//code to be executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is Ajax, but Ajax is not a language.
Ajax is:

> Asynchronous
>   Javascript
>   And
>   XML

You use normal standard-methods of Javascript to send requests to a server and then process the results to update the content of the html-document. For communication with the server you can use XML, but there is no need the stick on XML. I prefere JSON because it produces less traffic.

XML:

> eXtended
>   Markup
>   Language

JSON:

> Java-
>   Script
>   Object
>   Notation